# SELECT CAST(SUM(`foo`) AS UNSIGNED) AS ‘bar’, … works in phpMyAdmin but php code generates Swift.DecodingError “No value”

Tags: php, mysqli

Summing columns as integers works in phpMyAdmin SQL:

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(`foo1`) AS UNSIGNED) AS ‘bar1’, CAST(SUM(`foo2`) AS UNSIGNED) AS ‘bar2’ FROM `FUBAR`
```

However, the autogenerated SQL --> $sql php code not so much:

```
$sql = “SELECT CAST(SUM(`foo1`) AS UNSIGNED) AS /‘bar1/’, CAST(SUM(`foo2`) AS UNSIGNED) AS /‘bar2/’ FROM `FUBAR`”;
```

print(error):

```
dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.})))
```

The swift and json is okay enough to get a single row of integers without SUM() or COUNT():

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `FUBAR` WHERE userID = 4";
// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
// If so, then create a results array and temp to hold the data
$resultArray = array();
$tempArray = array();
// Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
    // Add each row into our results array
    $tempArray = $row;
    array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }
echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
mysqli_close($con);
```

So I’d appreciate insight into how the SELECT SUM() and COUNT() commands, as formatted above, are generating the Code=3840 "No value" error, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/'bar1/'` is not valid SQL. You should use one of bar1 or `bar1` e.g.

```
$sql = "SELECT CAST(SUM(`foo1`) AS UNSIGNED) AS bar1, CAST(SUM(`foo2`) AS UNSIGNED)) AS bar2 FROM `FUBAR`"
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/985ff5e/4)

Comment: First CAST and then SUM

Comment: @Noman CAST and then SUM can yield a completely different result to SUM and then CAST (e.g. for three data values 3.4, 3.4 and 3.4 CAST and then SUM gives 9 where SUM and then CAST gives 10). You should respect what the OP wrote in his query.

Comment: No change either see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/174312/1 always 9.  i don't think OP asked about that

Comment: @Noman that's because you declared foo1 and foo2 as INT. Try declaring them as FLOAT..

Comment: Data values and data types are two different things, different structure different statement however OP didn't specify the data type as far as he concern about the statement/query generated in-valid JSON.

Comment: @Noman sure but since we don't know what data type OP is using we shouldn't change the structure of his query when it could change the result.

Comment: Yes /'bar1/' is not SQL ... it's the SQL -> $sql php code generated by phpMyAdmin, where when I change to 'bar1' generates error = (Error?) nil, as things are now.

Comment: @Norman About a week ago I posted more representative Swift-Decodable JSON php code but got downvoted -5 real fast without comment. Agree problem likely matching data types, wherein my struct Decodable are String? and the $sql GETs a row of INT ok, and CAST(SUM( generates bigint ... but somehow not as valid JSON ... have tried struct float , double, but still not right combination

Comment: Since `$sql SELECT * FROM FUBAR` can read a row of Int, and `SQL CREATE TABLE FUBARsums SELECT CAST(SUM` creates row of bigint,  I changed data type from `struct Fubars: Decodable { let foo1: String?, let foo2: String?}` to `foo1: Int, foo2: Int`. However trying to GET FUBARsums row of bigint via `$sql SELECT * FROM FUBARsums` now returns: `typeMismatch(Swift.Int, Swift.DecodingError.Context(_JSONKey  ... (stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: Optional(0)) ... debugDescription: "Expected to decode Int but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: @ehounder your phpmyadmin might need updating? my version (4.6.6) gives appropriate PHP code: `$sql  = 'SELECT CAST(SUM(\`foo1\`) AS UNSIGNED) AS bar1, SUM(CAST(\`foo2\` AS UNSIGNED)) AS bar2 FROM \`FUBAR\`';`

Comment: @ehounder Also sorry about the 'bar1' suggestion, that isn't valid in MySQL. I have removed it from the answer.

Comment: All good Nick, re "your phpmyadmin might need updating?" Yes I had checked the MySQL Apache and php versions on my VPS and found php 7.0 "installed" ... but just checking again, it was not "applied" or whatever. So learning to set up my VPS, which sadly is still not running the above $sql for anything but SELECT *. Meaning the problem is still with my VPS set up, I'll be looking into.